# Code completion for multi-parameter method names in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, code-completion

In Xcode4, I'm finding that I can't get code completion to readily narrow for multi-parameter method names where the first part is common.  For example, consider the following methods from [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate):

```
- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
- tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
- tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:
...
```

The list goes on; there are quite a few methods that start `tableView`.  If I type "tableView", the list is long and not quickly navigated.  If I type "tableView:", code completion is exited as soon as I type the colon (:).  If I type a run-on such as "tableViewview", completion also exits, presumably as it no longer literally matches the first method name part.

Is there some way to complete via the keyboard on such a list without resorting to either mousing around or clattering out a random number of arrow key hits to navigate the long list?  I'm having a hard time believing that code completion for multi-parameter Objective-C methods is so limited, but neither experimentation nor documentation have proved illuminating thus far.

*Update for clarification:*
Above I'm referring to completion of a method declaration (e.g. in a .m file), not of a method call.  For method calls, Xcode 4.x does completion for each method parameter part independently; this works great.  The problem above only applys to declarations, generally when starting to write a new method implementation in a .m file.

Comment: I am facing the same problem !

Answer (score 6):

It does seems that the behavior you expect is (unfortunately) not implemented in Xcode. However, I've found a partial solution: code completion works when you specify the complete first part of the multi-parameter method, i.e. if you type this (with space at the end)

```
- tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and press ESCAPE key then the code completion dialog will appear and you will be able to keep typing the rest of the method name.

You are probably wondering:

> "Oh boy, do I really have to type in this long preamble just to get
>   my code completion?"

Code snippets to the rescue! You just have to type the preamble once and [convert it into snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303217/can-i-add-my-own-code-snippets-to-xcode-4). I found it's best to configure it the following way, **don't forget to add space** at the end of code part, it will make things easier.

[image: Ima]

How should you use the thing you've just created? In your .m file start typing `tabl` and Xcode will let you autocomplete the snippet for you. Once the preamble is placed press ESC to reveal the auto-completion list.

This solution is not very robust, since you have to create a snippet for every multi-part method you want to use, but it does save some time and there aren't that many multi-part method names that share the same prefix.

Answer (score 4):

I'm annoyed by this problem for quite a long time. Now I can verify that there is no way to do even in the newest Xcode 5, I submitted a bug report:
[Multi-parameter method declaration completion in Xcode](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=3113418)

Please dup it if you also want it.

Answer (score 2):

Oh sorry, it does not work that way I mentioned with protocol stubs like you wanted in your update.
I use **Accessorizer** for that, an app in the mac app store to fully implement the declaration of your delegate/protocol methods you want to implement. Hope that help a little bit.

Old post:

I use Tab <kbd>⇥</kbd> for this.
Example I often have:
You want one of many init methods in the code completion.

Then you don't want to scroll down or use to many keystrokes to get to the right method.

Hit <kbd>i</kbd> > hit Tab <kbd>⇥</kbd> > `init` is completed.

Hit Escape <kbd>⎋</kbd> and then <kbd>w</kbd> and then again Tab <kbd>⇥</kbd> for all these `initWith` methods.

You can even use <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd> / Escape <kbd>⎋</kbd> after the first parameter, **when** there is more than the method with only one parameter.

In your case hit <kbd>t</kbd> > Tab <kbd>⇥</kbd> > Escape <kbd>⎋</kbd> > <kbd>a</kbd> and Return <kbd>↩</kbd>, there you got your third method.
You can also jump to the previous code completion argument with Shift <kbd>⇧</kbd> + Tab <kbd>⇥</kbd>.