# How to run code snippets in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

While trying to learn Objective C from a book, I'd like to be able to run some code snippets like...

```
NSString *str = @"Hello, world!";
NSLog(@"Retain count is %d", [str retainCount]);
```

In Ruby I'd just put this in an snippet.rb file and run `ruby snippet.rb` from the terminal. JavaScript has jsfiddle.net.  Is there an equally easy way to do this with objective c?

Comment: `retainCount`? Really? :)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303217/can-i-add-my-own-code-snippets-to-xcode-4

Comment: @bbum book is teaching memory management

Comment: Then throw it away and get a better one.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil See this question on why using `-retainCount` is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Comment: @bryanjclark No, this one is about running snippets, the other one about integration in Xcode.

Comment: @Kitsune thanks, I'm just getting an overview of the environment now. However, I thought memory management was now taken care of by ARC so I wouldn't even have to think about it once I got into more of the nitty gritty

Comment: @jrturton feel free to recommend something better for the latest ios release. However, since I've got this already and just looking for an overview now, I'll finish it til I find something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on a Mac there's the handy [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/). It's $9.99 on the App Store but to me it was worth every penny.

Comment: is this just an ordinary code editor? looks like it to me...should I maybe see if there's an extension for my current editor (Sublime), or is there something more to CodeRunner that I should be aware of...

Comment: Code Runner let's you type a short snippet in a language of your choice and compiles, links and runs it. It prints the console output and lets you type input to stdin.

Comment: +1 coderunner is great. Before that I had dummy Xcode projects and unit tests all over the place.

Comment: has anyone used it on Mountain Lion?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe saw a bad review about it by someone using Mountain Lion

Comment: @NikolaRuhe is there documentation anywhere? it's opening my whole Macintosh hardrive in the editor. How do I just open one folder